# CM12 Samsung Galaxy Note 3: Unable to encrypt

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I am using the latest nightly of Cyanogenmod 12 (not 12.1) on my Note 3. I wanted to encrypt my phone but whenever I start the encryption process the phone shows a wireframed android and restarts. After that my external sd-card is not mounted. Another restart fixes this. There is no progress bar.

Are there any logs I could check? Has anybody experienced the same problems?

Thanks for any help!
Alex

Comment: How long have you let your phone to be doing the encryption? The process will take at least one hour but it is better to ensure more time for successful completion because of hardware dependency and other issues of the system. How did you install your CM12? Did you wipe both cache, system and data before doing the installation? I have had a similar issue when trying to do the encryption in a broken installation which I did in non-clean system (did not wipe sufficient things).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. It has to do with permissions. You should set SELinux to permissive before starting the encryption. To do that, access shell via adb shell or terminal emulator and type the following;

```
su
setenforce 0
```

Now if you go to about section, it will show SELinux as permissive instead of Enforcing. Now go to security -> encrypt and follow along the wizard. It will work.